# bootstrap - how to add background color for all the screen width when using containter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to use container (and not container-fluid) , but I still need to add background to all the remaining background( the background color differ from container to container). any idea how to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not pretty clear.
I will answer according to my understanding.

There should be only one container in the web application. Because it comes with fix width(not in %) i.e. ***1170px/970px/750px***.

So there should be only one to contain the website.
Now the only background out of container can be styled with the body tag.

```
body{
   background-color: #ddd; 
}
```